# How to create an object with generated name?

Tags: c#, class, object, generator

Normally I'd use

```
MyObject Obj1 = new MyObject(constructors);
```

But what I need is for the code to create an object for me and assign a name for it by itself based on variable.

```
string objectname = HakunaMatata
MyObject [I want HakunaMatata here] = new MyObject;

objectname = SomethingNew
MyObject [I want SomethingNew here] = new MyObject;
```

So how do I do it?

Comment: This seems to be a xy-problem, what you are actually trying to achieve? It seems you should try a `Dictionary<String, MyObject>`, the key is the name.

Comment: c# can't do that effectively. the compiler doesn't do anything like that. perhaps you want a dictionary instead?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're actually trying to do here.  Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: If I get it right you're generatig code. It should not take more than `string code = "MyObject "+ generatedName + " = new MyObject();";` and then write it into a file

Comment: are you using a code generator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for a [`Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx). This enables you to use a string as the "key" and have instances as the value.

```
string objectname = "HakunaMatata"
var myDictionary = new Dictionary<string,MyObject>();
myDictionary.Add(objectname, new MyObject()); // what a wonderful day!
```

you can later lookup & use your object by using the same key

```
MyObject makunaMatataInstance = myDictionary["HakunaMatata"]; // or use the variable "objectname" again
```

Comment: @Yvette nor am I, but this is pretty likely. Oh look, someone has downvoted. I have no idea why.

Comment: there's no indication that this is what the OP wants.

Comment: @DanielA.White - sometimes it helps to read between the lines when its an obviious XY. Theres a chance im wrong, but a pretty good chance im right. Ive seen a thousand similar questions.

Comment: Should you not then mark as duplicate :)

Comment: @Mfusiki, possibly. But unlike the many duplicates I do hammer, this one doesnt have one canonical answer that immediately jumps out at me.

Comment: Don't beat yourself up over downvotes too much, its only -2 points vs the +30 points you got for the three people who upvoted.

Comment: pfft, Im not beating myself up so much as trying to point out that DV an answer given in good faith, which probably asnwers the question and almost certainly helps the OP understand is just dumb.

Comment: Thank you - I'm a total noob to programming and couldnt even phrase my problem precisely, but this is exactly what I needed, thank you.

Comment: Oh look. OP ticks answer. Surprise surprise.  @Bronsoner you're most welcome.